# properties hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, dbunit

how i can load properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml` as String to my java program?

I want to create `IDataBaseTester` with this properties or tell me another way for create `IDataBaseTester` from `hibernate.cfg.xml`

`HibernateUtil` for create session

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use Hibernate 3?

Comment: Hibernate 4.* + 
do I have another way to write properties to my programm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `AnnotationConfiguration` with Hibernate 4. Just use `Configuration`.

To get properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
Properties properties = configuration.getProperties();
```

or

```
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = 
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure();
Map map = registryBuilder.getSettings();
```

Or you can try to use
[ConfigLoader](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/ConfigLoader.html)

Comment: @Ridov You are welcome. You can try a variant with `Configuration` too, if you have it in your code.